# Error 404, ajax event itemSelect Primefaces 5.2

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm having problems with EROR 404 when I clicked over item of Bar Chart, after that I get this error, I don´t know what is the problem with that.

I used, primefaces 5.2, java 8

According the documentation is add the next:

Java:

```
public ContractsBean() {
        modelChart = new BarChartModel();
         ChartSeries boys = new ChartSeries();
         boys.setLabel("Boys");
         boys.set("2004", 120);
         boys.set("2005", 100);
         boys.set("2006", 44);

         ChartSeries girls = new ChartSeries();
         girls.setLabel("Girls");
         girls.set("2004", 52);
         girls.set("2005", 60);
         girls.set("2006", 110);

         modelChart.addSeries(boys);
         modelChart.addSeries(girls);
         modelChart.setTitle("Bar Chart");
         modelChart.setLegendPosition("ne");

         Axis xAxis = modelChart.getAxis(AxisType.X);
         xAxis.setLabel("Gender");

         Axis yAxis = modelChart.getAxis(AxisType.Y);
         yAxis.setLabel("Births");
         yAxis.setMin(0);
         yAxis.setMax(200);
        }

    public BarChartModel getModelChart() { return modelChart; }

    public void itemSelectido(ItemSelectEvent event) {
     FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,
    "Item selected", "Item Index: " + event.getItemIndex() +
    ", Series Index:" + event.getSeriesIndex());

     FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
        System.out.println("chart impresooo");
     }
```

JSP:

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 60%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; margin-top: auto; margin-bottom: auto;">
                                    <p:chart type="bar" model="#{contractsBean.modelChart}">
                                        <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{contractsBean.itemSelectido}" />
                                    </p:chart>
                                    <p:growl id="growl"/>
                                </div>
```

[image: after I clicked the item bar display the error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things that maybe are missing in your post, but:

1) You need to annotate your Bean with `@ManagedBean`

2) You need to declare the BarChartModel as an class attribute `private BarChartModel modelChart;`

3) You should have your chart and ajax inside a form, like this:

```
<h:form>
    <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" />
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 60%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; margin-top: auto; margin-bottom: auto;">
        <p:chart type="bar" model="#{contractsBean.modelChart}">
            <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{contractsBean.itemSelectido}" update="growl" />
        </p:chart>
        <p:growl id="growl"/>
    </div>
</h:form>
```

4) Notice that I've also added an `update="growl"` on the `p:ajax` tag

Comment: 1 is invisibly present otherwise it would not even display anything  2 is invisibly present, otherwise there would be a compile error.

Comment: @Kukeltje what about 3 and 4?

Comment: 4 is superflous, leaving 3 which had better being asked in a comment and if it was the cause of a problem, check if a duplicate exists and if not, create a specific answer.. But that is me, what I would have done.

Comment: @Kukeltje I've answered with a few observations in order to help, that's it. Thanks for the suggestions, but I'm only trying to help

Comment: Ohh yes, that´s work for me!!! thanks a lot, I lacked the number 3.